# GET params with URI rounting/ Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes, get

```
$route['ajax/get/mail'] = "mail/get_mail_by_params";
```

I am trying to request *ajax/get/mail?user_id=123&foo=bar&bar=foo*

And params it in controller:

```
$foo = $this->input->get('foo')
```

But $_GET in *ajax/get/mail* variable is empty!

I suggest, that routing doesn’t supports GET paramets. What to do?

Comment: It works fine for me.  What if you go to mail/get_mail_by_params?user_id=123&foo=bar&bar=foo in you browser?  Does this work?

Comment: It works, but I want to have /ajax/get/mail?foo=bar&bar=foo

Comment: I don't know. Both work for me. /ajax/get/mail?foo=bar&bar=foo works also. Can you think of any custom configuration you might have done to your CI installation that could cause this?  Any Apache rewrite rules?  Any changes to the CI core libraries?

Comment: No changes. Just see the screen: http://habrastorage.org/storage/cc681603/70c3d417/18b92522/aab576cd.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the MY_Input library? http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MY_Input/

Also, I think you may need to update your URI Protocol in config.php to PATH_INFO.

> $config['uri_protocol']    = "PATH_INFO";